# How do I display attributes of table in oracle using python?

Tags: python, sql, oracle, cx-oracle

I connected Python to Oracle.

I am trying to display the attributes of the table using python i.e 
I want to display table schema. I am using 'describe' statement but while executing it gives me an error `' Invalid SQL Statement'.`

I have done the following:

```
queryString = 'Describe Customer'
onCursor.execute(queryString)
```

"Customer" is the table name

Comment: You probably connected Python to Oracle. Please describe how you did it :)

Comment: Also, could it be that you need to `USE database` first?

Comment: I did that but it doesn't work :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In below sql you replace the table and owner name. It gives the columns names and datatype of column.

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME='table_name' and OWNER='schema name'
```

Answer (score 6):

If you need SQL statement columns description then just use cursor.description. If you need exact table schema the select from ALL_TAB_COLUMNS oracle view:

```
    cnn = cx_Oracle.connect(cnn_str)
    cursor = cnn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM dual")
    print(cursor.description)

    cursor.execute("select * from ALL_TAB_COLUMNS where table_name = 'DUAL'")
    print(cursor.fetchall())

    cursor.close()
```

It will provede output:

```
[('DUMMY', <class 'cx_Oracle.STRING'>, 1, 4, None, None, 1)]
[('SYS', 'DUAL', 'DUMMY', 'VARCHAR2', None, None, 1, None, None, 'Y', 1, None, None, 1, b'X', b'X', 1, 0, 1, datetime.datetime(2009, 4, 25, 23, 49, 59), 1, 'CHAR_CS', 1, 'YES', 'NO', 2, 1, 'B', 'NO', 'YES', 'NONE', 'NO', 'NO', None, None, None)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Now [this](http://cx-oracle-users.narkive.com/suaWH9nn/cx-oracle4-3-1-describe-table-query-is-not-working) is a bit of an old source, but I think your issue is that `describe` is not really a query.

Try getting the information from the data dictionary instead. Documentation for Oracle 12.2 is [here](https://docs.oracle.com/database/122/CNCPT/data-dictionary-and-dynamic-performance-views.htm#CNCPT1209).

Comment: The solution from the old source works. Thank you for the help